# Does childhood familiarity with weather patterns predict the influence of those patterns on mood?

Tags: mood

Though similar to [this question](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/9688/why-does-weather-often-affect-mood), in my opinion the difference is large enough for my question to stand alone:

I observed that specific weather conditions affect my mood. That's rater trivial, sure.

"Specific" in this context means, any conditions which are similar to those which often happened around the place I grew up (Northern Germany, with sometimes rather bleak winters, a horizon far away and lots of wind). E.g., I really like it, when the wind blows in my face, though the sky may be grey and a slight drizzle is in said wind. When others curse the weather for being bleak and cold, I tend to be rather happy. My sister confirmed my observations for herself. To be honest, I also like summer days - as long as they're not stiffling hot and a slight breeze is going.

Is there any research on this topic, e.g. how weather similar to where you grew up affects your mood, whether this is a general phenomenon for all people or rather for people from specific areas?

Comment: I'm not sure this question has a good answer; I removed the part asking for other people's observations, stackexchange isn't meant as a discussion forum and such answers would be off-topic. I also tried to make the title of your question closer to the specific question you have, feel free to edit again if I've missed the mark.